# Laravel trusted proxies

Tags: laravel

We record client's ip address. We added `https://www.example_domain/` to application. So request is going to the site before coming to the server. When I checked ip addresses, I see all ips are the same which is website's assigned ip addresses. I added this ip addresses to trusted proxies in laravel. Now I am getting client ip's addresses.

I want to understand what is going on.

When I get `$request->ip()` is the process like below?

- Laravel check if ip is in trusted proxy, if it is, look at X-Forwarded-for address then assume that ip as client's ip address?
- if ip is not in trusted proxies, laravel assume that ip is client's ip?

If my assumptions above are correct, what happens there are more than one proxy? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can add a list of trusted proxies with `setTrustedProxyIpAddresses` function. see [here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.html#method_setTrustedProxyIpAddresses).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = [
        '192.168.1.1',
        '192.168.1.2',
    ];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
}
```

Comment: that's not what the question is about !